# viewing a table based on a previous id

Tags: php, sql

I have a table set up called Modules, that once a user is logged in it brings up the modules related to that user, this works fine. At the side of each module in the table I have a lessons link. once the user clicks on that I want it to display the lessons based on the module ID.

Any help would be great full.

My Module code in case I need to add something to it is as follows;

```
<?
include('../inc/security.inc.php');
authorise();

// Include databse connection file
include('../inc/connection.inc.php');

// Connect to the database
connect();

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblModule WHERE userID = '$userID'" ;
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

and displaying the module table as follows;

```
<?php
// run a while loop through all records and create a new row for each one
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($result))

{

?>
<table class="myTable">
    <th class="col">Module ID</th>
    <th class="col">Module Title</th>
    <th class="col">Module Description</th>
    <th class="col">User ID</th>
    <th class="col">Manage</th>
</tr>

    <tr class="row">
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->moduleID; ?></td>
    <td class="cell"><?php echo $record->moduleTitle; ?></td>
    <td class="cell"><?php echo $record->moduleDescription; ?></td>
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->userID; ?></td>
    <td class="cell"><a href="./lessons.php?moduleID=<? echo $record->moduleID; ?>">Lessons</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?
}
// clean up after ourselves by cleating $result and closing the database connection
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();

?>
```

Then so far in the lesson table i have;

```
<?
include('../inc/security.inc.php');
authorise();

// Include databse connection file
include('../inc/connection.inc.php');

// Connect to the database
connect();

$moduleID = $_SESSION['moduleID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLessons WHERE moduleID = '$moduleID'" ;
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

With the result been displayed as;

```
<?php
// run a while loop through all records and create a new row for each one
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
?> 
<table class="myTable">
    <th class="col">LessonID</th>
    <th class="col">Lesson Number</th>
    <th class="col">Lesson Description</th>
    <th class="col">ModuleID</th>
    <th class="col">Lesson Plan ID</th>
    <th class="col">Manage</th>
</tr>

<tr class="row">
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->lessonID; ?></td>
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->lessonNumber; ?></td>
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->lessonDescription; ?></td>
<td class="cell"><?php echo $record->moduleID; ?></td>
 <td class="cell"><?php echo $record->lessonPlanID; ?></td>
 </tr>

</table>
<?
}
// clean up after ourselves by cleating $result and closing the database connection
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the moduleID as a query string variable to lessons.php, but in lessions.php you're looking for it in session data.

```
$moduleID = $_SESSION['moduleID'];
```

Try:

```
$moduleID = isset($_GET['moduleID']) ? $_GET['moduleID'] : false;
if ( $moduleID ) {
    $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM tblLessons WHERE moduleID = %d', $moduleID);
    $result = @mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    // No moduleID, so show an error message, redirect user, or the like    
}
```

Note that I'm using sprintf so that $moduleID is converted to a digit. The code you're using - passing the value directly to MySQL - is dangerous.  Google:  "sql injection".

If $moduleID can in fact be a string, then you need to take extra steps to ensure that the data is sanitized before being passed to MySQL, e.g.

```
$moduleID = isset($_GET['moduleID']) ? $_GET['moduleID'] : false;
if ( $moduleID ) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblLessons WHERE moduleID = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($moduleID));
    $result = @mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    // No moduleID, so show an error message, redirect user, or the like    
}
```

You should also consider switching to PDO, as the mysql_ functions are depreciated.  PDO is a much easier, safer way to interact with MySQL.

Comment: That worked perfect, Thank you for your suggestions and your quick response.